# How to pass javascript function's output to asp button CommandArgument

Tags: javascript, c#, c#-4.0

1. I want to pass java script function value to command argument of  button and want to get in EditGuest data method of my cs page.
2. Here is the EditGeuest function

   ```
   function EditGeuest(){ 
       var gstDetails = document.getElementById('<%#cmbGuestName1.ClientID %>');
       var guestID = gstDetails.value;

   }
   ```
3. Here is the button code

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="Editbtn" OnClientClick="EditGeuest() OnClick="EditGuestdata" CommandArgument=guestID runat="server"  Text="Edit" />
   ```

Comment: any body is there who can help me

Comment: OnClientClick="EditGeuest()" I think there is a missing " no ?

Comment: what is missing

Comment: I mean double quotes "

Comment: no sir i think you are not getting my problem its not related to double quotes

Comment: @K.Ariche I think that is only a typo here, because otherwise, the whole thing would not run at all

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this:

```
document.getElementById('Editbtn').CommandArgument = guestID
```

Your button tag must already contain the attribute `CommandArgument` with or without a value.

Comment: no sir i want to pass the guestID to CommandArgument so that i can get iyt on my cs page.

Comment: so where i need to put this code in java script function or somewhere else

Comment: Yes, this has to go right at the end of your existing javascript function

Comment: which exception?

Comment: Change your button to this: `<asp:Button id="Editbtn" OnClientClick="EditGeuest()" OnClick="EditGuestdata" CommandArgument="" runat="server" Text="Edit" />`